# How to store and retrieve data from linux binary file

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I'm using arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ in order to compile a c++ code that will run on an embedded Linux device.

I'm using the arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ under windows and get as output the binary file that will run on the Linux machine.

In order to set the embedded device with a new binary, I need to create an archive file (zip) with the binary file and with some more settings files.

till far it all OK.

I need to automate that so that the archive file will be created automatically at name of the version of the binary file.

Currently, we keep the version as just a simple constant std::string variable in the code. We use that string when printing diagnostic, logging, etc.

How can I read that from the version binary file?

Or may other methods to achieve that goal?

I thought may to store it in some constant place in the binary file and read it from there but really don't know how to do that without making the binary corrupted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the file automatically, so I assume you are first compiling it and then making an archive with the resulting binary.

You could store the version in a text file, and `#include` that file in your code:

```
const std::string version = 
#include "version.txt"
;
```

In the `version.txt`:

```
"version string"
```

And when making the archive, you can easily parse the version from the text file.

Comment: I'd actually do it with a macro (passed with `-D`) but yeah.

Answer (score 2):

Ville is correct.

You're currently doing it backwards!

Your build system should provide the version to the executable, not the other way around. Once this is fixed, your build system can provide the same version to other elements, such as your ZIP filename.

Ideally the version would be generated from version control autonomously, but you could specify it in the build command if really necessary.

It's possible to pull some string from the binary (think `nm`, if there's a Windows equivalent), but that's really the reverse way to do it.

Comment: Indeed that is a simple and good answer! 
It will be still interesting to know how to store some data to a binary executable file and read it back